# Add parameter for process

Tags: php, telnet

I want to simulate Telnet using PHP. My problem is: I use `proc_open` to execuse command telnet. While running telnet, how can I send parameter for this command, example: `open 192.168.1.1`

Thanks!

Comment: try this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php

Comment: @TrinhThanh +1 for the code, -1 for posting it as a comment...

Comment: @Rufinus you're right! but, I believe that he can achieve the same things he wanted using SSH. don't you think ?

Comment: depends on what he is trying to do. SSH is just what it is, telnet can be used to connect to all kind of ports. e.g imap, smtp, and many others more.

Comment: you're right! let's ask the guy :) @Trinh what are you trying to do with telnet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proc_open` is like a more flexible `popen` so to write to the process you use fwrite on the pipe.

see the example #1 on http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php